# Get a javascript variable to a php one

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://web.itoday.gr/load.js"</script>
<p><script type="text/javascript"> datesmart(0); namesprefix(0); names(0); </script></p>
<p><script type="text/javascript"> datesmart(1); namesprefix(1); names(1); </script></p>
```

I want to get the variable names(1) to a php variable. How will i be able to do this ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access JS variables in PHP. You have two options

1) Set the value of `names(1)` to a html element and access the value from that html element (like hidden field, span etc)

2) Use AJAX

As an example:

Add hidden field in the case you are submitting the value to another page using form.

```
<input type="hidden" id="nameval">
```

Instead of `hidden` field, use elements like `span` or `div` to display the value of the `names(1)` in the html page like,

```
<span id="nameval"></span>
```

Set the value of this hidden input field (and html in the case of span/div)  using jquery. Call this function in appropriately depending on your need. Firstly, you need to include the jquery library as shown below.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()     // when the document is ready
{
    $("#nameval").val(names(1));    // set the value of element with id nameval if you are using hidden field

    $("#nameval").html(names(1));   // use this in the case of span/div
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how PHP can access variable using your first option ?

Comment: In case of hidden field you have to POST it to server to be accessed by PHP, either by ajax or normal HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on server and javascript in browser . You need to send a ajax request to access value from javascript.

On script load send a ajax request with data to the php script you want to access this variable.

Comment: is it difficult ? cause i dont know ajax at all.

Comment: Nope, include jQuery in html file and send request as explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)